# "To do any classification or regression, we need the fully-connected layer as the output layer"

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, conv-neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

I was going through some papers and tutorials and everywhere it is mentioned, "To do any classification or regression, we need the fully-connected layer as the output layer". Why so? what's the intuition behind it? I am unable to correlate with mine understanding. What if I use dropouts in the final layer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, dropouts are a way of tuning incorrect training from the primacy effect: throw out a few intermediate conclusions, and trust that the valid ones will naturally reappear.  Dropout is not generally used on the final layer.

The fully-connected final layer is a NN (neural network) idiom for classification: it gives every perceptron in the penultimate layer (the one just before) a weight to influence the ultimate (final) classification.

The general idea is that the penultimate layer contains the highest-level abstractions and relationships that your model uses to make its classification decisions.  Each of those gets a "voice" (a weight) for each of the possible classifications.  The result is a FC (fully-connected) layer at the end.